# How to make an element inherit of parent element value

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out the correct way to make a div class inherit the parent div height so that when I do for example, padding-top: 100% , it puts the element at 100% of the parent div.

Here's my code:

CSS

```
#globalContainer{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header-out{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#header{
    width: 940px; /* Set to % when possible */
    height: 240px; /* Set to % when possible */
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: white;
}

#header .title{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="globalContainer">
        <div id="header-out">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="title">Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

At the moment, my Test appears at the very bottom of the page inside of the bottom of my header...

Thanks !

**EDIT:** I am now trying to add a logo next to my title, I used this code:

```
#header .title{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2.5%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#header .logo{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Problem is, it overlaps my title, starting where my title would end if I did not use the left: 2.5%

I tried to remove the float: left, it doesn't change anything...

Anyone can help on this ?

Comment: Do you want `.title` to be displayed at the bottom of `#header`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I was able to get the result I wanted by using "top" instead of "padding-top", however I am not quite sure that this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Okay so I did a couple tests, if I use position: relative along with top & left, I get the position that I want but the float doesn't work properly. If I use margin-left and margin-top, the positioning is based on the whole screen, but the float works properly... No idea which way I should be taking from there though

Comment: Ok this is really weird, the margin-left 100% position the element correctly, but not the margin-top...